# editor for Nullable in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, datetime, nullable

I have create a class inherit `ICustomTypeDescriptor` for dynamicly load properties in PropertyGrid. I need to edit `DateTime` inside. So if type is `Nullable<DateTime>` standart calendar editor not shown but for `DateTime` works perfectly but I cant leave editor field empty (like i want to set value to `null`).
Note. Im not using class attributes, so I need somehow to solve problem using `ICustomTypeDescriptor` and `PropertyDescriptor` what im using.

Nobody knows?